# how to stay on same page after alert in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

`onClick=validateForm()` it shows alert if it is blank but it goes to next page("action=some.php") so any idea how to be on same page after alert?

```
function validateForm() {    
  var x = document.forms["uploadForm"]["userImage"].value;    
  if (x == "") {           
    alert("Choose the file !!!!!");
    return false;
  }
  var p = document.forms["uploadForm"]["Start_Date"].value;
  var q = document.forms["uploadForm"]["End_Date"].value;
  if (p == "" && q=="") {
    alert("Select the date !!!!!");
    return false;   
  }
  var radio = document.forms["uploadForm"]["radio"].value;
  if (radio == "") {
    alert("Select the Radio !!!!!");
    return false;
  }     
}
```

Comment: Show us what triggers the alert, i.e. the event handlers, and we'll tell you how to prevent the default action. Really all you have to do is always `return false`.

Comment: onClick=" return validateForm()"

Comment: How about removing the action and having the function call the PHP script when you need it?

Comment: Use preventDefault()? Because none of your cases seems to be able to submit the form

Comment: Thank you so much @epascarello it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `onClick="return validateForm()"` in place of `onClick=validateForm()`. Thank you so much  @epascarello for your quick answer.